# Spring Boot endpoint gets interupted with 302 unexpectedly after multiple requests on Chrome

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, google-chrome

Apologies for the long read but I really don't know how to ask for help on this and have exhausted everything else I can think of. So if anyone can give me any clues or paths forward I would be very appreciative.

We have a Java Spring backend (Spring Boot 2.4.13 currently.) It started as an MVC project so we have some controllers that return ModelAndView objects but we're moving to a fully rest API situation with a vue frontend.

The situation is, we have a 3rd party vendor (LS) that we are trying to integrate with our system. LS has a Single Sign On (SSO) process for logins. The exchange is pretty simple, on their site there is an SSO button the user clicks. They send us a POST request with a string token at a URL we provide. Then they expect us to send a form over POST back to a URL they provide. And now the user will be logged into LS with the information we send over with the form.

Our solution was to create an endpoint at /sso that accepts a POST request (the URL we provide them.) This endpoint is relatively simple, it stores their token in a session variable and directs the user with ModelAndView to a jsp where the form is auto filled and auto submitted to do the POST back and log the user into LS. There is a separate GET endpoint we use to get the user data to auto fill the form.

If the user is not logged into our system yet, they get directed to our login page and have to go through the process all over again.

So, this all works perfectly fine. If the user is using Firefox browser. You can log in and out of LS using the SSO button over and over or even let your session completely expire, login on our site and then go do the SSO button on LS and it will log you in fine every time as far as I can tell.

However, on Chrome (and Edge and presumably any chromium browser) it works fine at first. You can log in with the SSO button as expected. You can even logout and back in some before the issue occurs. Or you can just wait a few minutes. But it consistently happens after a few minutes. Clicking the SSO button after those first few minutes instead will send the POST request and our server will respond with a 302 and direct the user to our home page (still logged in.) This happens every time after that until browser cache is cleared.

The POST request from LS has no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate as its cache-control header. I have tried adding this to the response of our POST controller method as well. Thinking it has to be some kind of weird Chrome browser cache issue. None of that helped.

After doing some more tests I realized when the 302 starts, the call never actually makes it into our controller endpoint. Nothing in there gets triggered at all. I also tried making a servlet filter that just logs the status codes of every call coming into our server and I never see a 302 occur.

We don't have any kind of manually created 302 responses in our entire project either.

The location in the 302 response header has an extension to the login URL that is errorKey=rs.home.loginRequired. I tracked this down to a bean in our web security configuration. It is our LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint. So I'm guessing Chrome for some reason makes our server think the user is not logged in, but they are. It just ends up on our home page.

I'm at a complete loss here. The fact that it works on Firefox but not on Chrome AND it works on Chrome at first but doesn't after a while, makes me think it is some kind of cache issue specific to the browser but I tried all the cache related things I could think of... and since it seems like our server is sending the user to the home page under the 302's location of a login required redirect makes me wonder if there is some session saving problem, but since the user is still logged in, it doesn't seem to be a problem there either.

Any ideas, even if just to point me at a new path to start down would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone ends up here with something similar. Turns out that there is a big difference in the way Chrome and Firefox handle cookies by default. And Spring backend also defaults to match Chrome. Specifically, the same site policy for Chrome is Lax. Spring defaults to Lax. Firefox defaults to None.

In the end my problem was our Spring configuration nulled the same site policy, so it was allowing browsers to handle things and this is why Firefox was not causing a 302 when the request from the 3rd party site came through.

Setting spring to None; Secure allows both browsers to function the same. Specifically in regards to the session cookie, which was being lost on Chrome.